# Quotes in javascript string +variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't make it work, btn is a string here but 'licz' is a variable, I've tried anything, could someone help me and tell what is wrong with that ?
Licz is a counter from 1 to 100, i want that line to give something like

btn1, btn2 etc

> ```
>     $('#slider').append("<div id='btn ' + \'licz><i class='fa fa-circle fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>");
> ```

Can someone show me the proper way to do this ? I would be gratefull

Answer (score 2):

```
    $('#slider').append("<div id='btn" + licz + "'><i class='fa fa-circle fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to append it to your string like so:

```
 $('#slider').append("<div id='btn" + licz + "'><i class='fa fa-circle fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>");
```

Or if you are using ES6

```
$('#slider').append(`<div id='btn${licz}'><i class='fa fa-circle fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable is not appended correctly it needs to be like this:

`$('#test').append("<div id='btn '>" + licz + " <i class='fa fa-circle fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>");`

[**HERE**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/EZOppL) is an example of it working

Answer (score 0):

You need to stop and start the string appropriately where you want to. So you might instead like to try

```
$('#slider').append("<div id='btn " + licz + "><i class='fa fa-circle fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></div>");
```

Breaking the string properly with double quotes to allow you to insert the variable.